# Number of Pages for Appendix in Elsevier Template

Tags: page-numbering, appendix, els-cas

I met a problem when using the Elsevier template downloaded here:

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/

When I try to add an Appendix, the number of pages will exceed its limitation, for instance, Pages 10 of 9......

A minimal example could be found below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add
\usepackage{caption,setspace} % Add
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=normalfont]{subcaption}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period} % Add

\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.} % For Fig.
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
 
% Short title
\shorttitle{A}    

% Short author
\shortauthors{A et al}  

% Main title of the paper
\title [mode = title]{A}  

% -------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------- %

\begin{abstract}
B
\end{abstract}

% -------------------------------- Keywords -------------------------------- %

\begin{keywords}
\sep A
\end{keywords}

% -------------------------------- Introduction -------------------------------- %
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{1}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l Sl X }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text is always being here\\
        32    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\ 
        64    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        128   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        192   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} \\
        3200  & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab1}
\end{table*}

This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. VThis is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction.

\appendix
\section{Supplementary Materials}

This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. VThis is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction.

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l Sl X }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text is always being here\\
        32    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\ 
        64    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        128   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        192   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} \\
        3200  & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab2}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

May I know how to solve this problem? Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This way seems to work (your problem is that you are adding a float in the last page -alternative ways could possibly work-):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage{color} % Add
\usepackage{caption,setspace} % Add
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=normalfont]{subcaption}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period} % Add

\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.} % For Fig.
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}

\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
 
% Short title
\shorttitle{A}    

% Short author
\shortauthors{A et al}  

% Main title of the paper
\title [mode = title]{A}  

% -------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------- %

\begin{abstract}
B
\end{abstract}

% -------------------------------- Keywords -------------------------------- %

\begin{keywords}
\sep A
\end{keywords}

% -------------------------------- Introduction -------------------------------- %
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{1}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l Sl X }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text is always being here\\
        32    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\ 
        64    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        128   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        192   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} \\
        3200  & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab1}
\end{table*}

This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. VThis is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction.

\appendix
\section{Supplementary Materials}

This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. VThis is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction. This is an introduction.

\pagebreak

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
%\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
    \captionof{table}{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l Sl X }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text is always being here\\
        32    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\ 
        64    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        128   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        192   & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} \\
        3200  & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth, height=20mm, valign=M]{example-image} & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab2}
%\end{table*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! Let me check it now.

Comment: Will there be any way to add more pages? If I have many figures and tables in the Appendix.

Comment: Just use the minipage way to the last one figure or table... this will work.